# Dell 1397 WLan Mini-card does not recognize particular wifi in both recently installed dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, broadcom

Very grateful to the comunity and this post [Installing Broadcom Wireless..](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) which I think is the product of many invisible works, so thanks. I will not be posting this question if I didn't think it could be useful, regardless of the simplicity or complexity, and ignoring that maybe it was posted previously; if this is the case excuse in advance.

The title practically describes the entire issue, to clarify I checked in both OS that the wifi-card drivers are installed and actualized. I can see other wifi nets but not my own.

When reseted the router a re-configuration was made, lowering the WiFi standard from 802.11g to 802.11 b (I guess this is correct, which I'm sure is that the change was made from higher to lower hierarchy standard). After this change I was able to detect and connect to the wireless in both Ubuntu and Windows, but now once I reboot I can not see my wireless account anymore.

Below the output of

`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info`

[wireless-info.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23727189/)

And a caption of the modem specs
[image]

Comment: I know I can't see wifi on channel 13 here with broadcom drivers on BCM43142.

Comment: Please run the wireless script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-